# Online program for letting other people review your writing without hassle to them?

Tags: text-editor

When I have written something, (e.g. an essay), and I want someone to review it, I usually send it to them in a microsoft word file.

This is somewhat of a hassle to the people reviewing:

1. They have to download the file,
2. click on "mark changes for review"
3. save the file.
4. Send it back to me via email.

One obvious alternative, Google docs, does not have the feature of "mark changes for review", though it has the feature of "comments", but this is somewhat clumsy for reviewers who are in a hurry.

**I'd like the reviewing to be absolutely minimally a hassle for the reviewers.**

**Is there an online program that achieves this? i.e. a program such that**

1. I can just send them a link with my file.
2. They edit in the text itself, and it will automatically show up as a comment, or as red text.
3. They simply close the page and don't have to save.

Comment: There is a “suggesting” view on G docs. Have you tried that?